# Database values in textbox if select Combobox (arabic characters)

Tags: c#, sql, hyperlink, combobox, arabic

I have problem with Arabic character display in textbox using SQL database. I use the `nvarchar` type in SQL and when I select a Latin character in item combobox its work perfectly (img1), but when i try to select an Arabic item in combobox nothing happen in textbox 1 and 2 (img2).

The code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace testconnection
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SqlConnection con;
        private SqlCommand cmd;
        private SqlDataAdapter da;
        private DataTable dt;
        private SqlDataReader dr;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            combo();

        }

        void combo()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(
               @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\vemmi\Documents\user.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT usrs FROM usrtest", con);
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["usrs"]);

                }

                dr.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 c = new Form2();
            c.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(
                @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\vemmi\Documents\user.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usrtest WHERE usrs like '" + comboBox1.Text + "' ");

            cmd.Connection = con;

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (dr.Read())
                {

                      string p = dr["pwd"].ToString();
                      string n = dr["nbr"].ToString();


                      textBox2.Text = p;
                      textBox3.Text = n;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        }
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R339i.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'N' before the Arabic string in the query.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usrtest WHERE usrs like N'" + comboBox1.Text + "' ");
```